# замена знака минус на тильду в QString c++ qt

Tags: c++, qt

есть выражение например -5+(-12)-25 надо заменить все минус симвилы отрицательных чисел на знак ~ 
результат ~5+(~12)-25
помогите заменить

Comment: думаю, можно управится регуляркой. Где то такой `/([+-*/\(])\s*-/\1~/g`

Comment: @KoVadim Как по мне - из пушки по воробьям...

Comment: спасибо попробую ))

Comment: Из пушки - это писать парсер. Но тут  сразу много вопросов.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите функцию [`QString::replace`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#replace-8)

```
QString str = "-5+(-12)-25"
str.replace("-", "~");
```

Comment: Если бы все было так просто

Comment: Надо ж не огульно все минусы заменить

Comment: В чем же проблема?

Comment: мне нужно только заменить минус который озночает негативное число

Comment: @Artyom, Разве `-25` не отрицательное число? Советую описать, откуда возникла эта задача.

Comment: нет конечно ....  -5 + (-12) - 25    мне надо только заменить те минусы которые не оператор вычитание а знак минуса

Comment: напишите код если кто нибудь знает как решить эту задачу пож

Comment: @maestro, судя по всему, товарищ хочет отличить бинарный минус от унарного...

Comment: Если желаете воспользоваться регуляркой, предложенной KoVadim, то есть перегрузка функции replace, которая работает с регулярками. В документации она следующая за той, на которую я дал ссылку.

Comment: может подскажеш как заменить унарный минус на знак ~ из QString ?

Comment: не помогло рег выражение который написал KoVadim (((

Comment: (-?\\d+(?:[\\.,]\\d+(?:e\\d+)?)?) смотри это выражение берет из троки все числа и отрицательные и не отрицательные может поможеш изменить рег выражение чтобы взял только отрицательные ?